# How to read 2nd level sub-directory text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a little program which is supposed to read text from a text file.
The text file is contained in a sub-directory as follows:

Customer > Sub-directory 1 > Sub- directory 2 > Text file

The code I am using is:

```
Dim ti = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Customers\" & TextBox1.Text))

Dim du As String = Path.Combine(ti.FullName, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text + ".txt")

Dim ObjectReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(du)
```

Where:

- TextBox1 = Name of the Customer
- TextBox2 = Name of product
- TextBox3 = Reference

The error I am getting is:

“Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Customers\Biscuits\Reference.txt”.

Please how do I rectify this? I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you.

Comment: "I notice that the Name of the Customer is not being searched" -- what is the name off the customer?

Comment: @roryap - Thank you for your reply. Please assume it is Stephens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try:

```
 Dim ti2 = (Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Customers\" & TextBox1.Text))

    Dim du = Path.Combine(ti2, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text + ".txt")
```